# Align in itemize - change preferences

Tags: math-mode, align, itemize

How could I achieve that the itemize name, i.e. the (b) is on the same high than the A and that the cases-environment start on the left rather than centered?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[$(a)$] A
\item[$(b)$] \begin{align*}A&=\begin{cases}S,&\text{if ... }\\S,&\text{if ...}\end{cases}\\&=\end{align*}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: $\begin{aligned}[t] .... \end{aligned} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard answer is to switch to inline math (`$...$`) and in there use the `aligned` environment

Also added a more proper method of getting numbered items

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem} % better lists
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item A
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]A&=\begin{cases}S,&\text{if ... }\\S,&\text{if ...}\end{cases}\\&=\end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```